# Soql Query on custom objects using junction object

Tags: soql

i have three custom objects.

`Bank_Account__c(Parent) --->Bank_transaction__c(child)`

`Bank_Account__c(Parent) --->Bank_statement__c(child)`

`Bank_transaction__c` fields are `date__c`,
`credit__c`,
`debit__c`

`Bank_statement__c` fields are 
`start_date__c`,
`end_date__c`

I just want to write a single query to get the records of `Bank_transaction__c` which `date__c` is in between `start_date__c` and `end_date__c` of `bank_statement__c` object. How can i achieve this

Comment: You can't write a single query for this; this isn't SQL. You'll have to query for the statement(s) you want, then query the transactions for those dates. Alternatively, you could make a lookup field on the transaction for the statement, and have it populated via a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

As there could be hundreds of statements per bank account and tens of thousands of transactions per bank account I give a big +1 to the lookup field to relate the statements and transactions so later queries are then simple.

Fyi, you can query a parent and multiple child objects in a single SOQL request using [relationship queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm). (This is not the same thing as being able directly relate the date fields of the two child objects.) But without the relationship between Bank_transaction__c and Bank_statement__c, some careful code would be needed to avoid exponential cost trying to relate those objects via the dates:

```
for (Bank_Account__c a : [
        select name, ...,
                (select start_date__c, end_date__c from Bank_statements__r order by start_date__c),
                (select date__c, credit__c, debit__c from Bank_transactions__r order by date__c)
        from Bank_Account__c
        where ...
        order by name
        ]) {
    // Need a better algorithm than this to avoid the doubly nested loop.
    // E.g. a Map key with a date and a start/end date where if the
    // date in one key is within the start/end of another key they are equal.
    for (Bank_statement__c s : a.Bank_statements__r) {
        for (Bank_transaction__c t : a.Bank_transactions__r) {
            if (t.date__c >= s.start_date__c && t.date__c <= s.end_date__c) {
                // t belongs to s
            }
        }
    }
}
```